# Pagination with lot of pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i got a question about pagination. First of all, im new at html and javascript.
Ok, here is my doubt. Im building a website from cero. Im not using any web editor.

I filled the index.html with enough content (based on what i think is enough).
Now i want to add a new page with new content, and this page will be my new index.html, and the first index.html will be page-2.html (for example).

And I will be adding a new page like every 3 days, so what happens when I got more than 30 or 40 pages?

I know how to do a pagination, but i want to know if there`s a way to have a pagination without having to change name of pages every time?

Like a dynamic pagination or something like that. I dont know how to do it. I have been searching but I found nothing.

-Is there a way to do it with javascript?

-I don´t have knowledge about PHP.

-Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: There is virtually no reason to roll your own pagination solution. Most PHP frameworks/ javascript libraries  handle pagination for you.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll take that in consideration. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the datatables.net library. It paginates for you: https://datatables.net/reference/api/

Comment: Thanks for the answer it really helped. :D

Answer (score 0):

Only javascript solution :

You don't have to rename pages nor having multiple pages.
What you need to do is create a sinlge long pages with content separated liek this for exemple

```
<article>
  Content 1
</article>
<article>
  Content 2
</article>
...
```

And then simply do a pagination since you know how to do that.
And display element like, first of pagination show article 1 to 5
and `display:none` the other etc...

However this is clearly not a good idea mostly due to time of loading. The way you should do is to use php and sql to store your content in database and display it calling the server (with php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really help. i think the best way is using php or a js library./plugin